# leakcanary исправление утечки

Tags: android, android-library

Как исправить утечку по отчету из `leakcanary`? Утечка на 1.5 мегабайта.
Фото:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

mainView - ссылка на интерфейс активити
ClickListener в адаптере:

```
private class OnItemClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        private String songId;

        private OnItemClickListener(String songId) {
            this.songId = songId;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mainView.showSelectedSong(songId, listPhotoLoaded);
        }
    }
```

ClickListener одной из View:

```
private class OnItemToneClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        private int clickPosition;

        private OnItemToneClickListener(int clickPosition) {
            this.clickPosition = clickPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (clickPosition != currentCheckedRadioButton) {
                radioButtonsTones.get(currentCheckedRadioButton).setChecked(false);
                radioButtonsTones.get(clickPosition).setChecked(true);
                currentCheckedRadioButton = clickPosition;
            }
        }
    }
```

Слушатель по нажатию избранного:

```
@OnClick(R.id.imageButtonFavorite)
    void favoriteClick() {
        currentSongPresenter.setFavoriteState();
    }
```

Ещё:

```
@Override
    public void showFavoriteDialog(boolean addFavorite) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mainActivity);
        if (addFavorite) {
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_favorite_add);
        } else {
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_favorite_delete);
        }

        dialog.findViewById(R.id.parentLayout).setOnClickListener(v -> dialog.dismiss());
        dialog.show();
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(dialog::dismiss, 3000);
        setFavoriteImageState(addFavorite);
    }
```

Comment: Вложите фото в вопрос, а не по ссылке

Comment: @VladimirParfenov Очень длинное фото, по этому сделал по ссылке

Comment: Нужно разбивать на 2 фото, сжимать для того, чтобы они не весили по нескольку мегабайт и прикладывать. Надо уважать правила оформления.

Comment: Так не понятно. Нужно анализировать дамп памяти и смотреть код полностью. Попробуйте в студии сделать все действия приводящие к утечке, потом вызвать GC, а потом сразу дамп возьмите и посмотрите то там в дампе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё просто: нижняя строка говорит что в памяти виснет `CurrentSongFragment`,
строка выше указывает где создаётся удерживающая его ссылка.
Беглый взгляд по стеку и вот что мы видим.
В классе `CurrentBaseFragment` Вы вешаете обработчик на кнопку в тулбаре, в коде которого ссылаетесь на инстанс фрагмента (скорее всего неявно - обращение к полям и методам). Но тулбар живёт дольше фрагмента и удерживает его в памяти ссылкой в обработчике кнопки.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по цепочке, ссылка `sDefaultWindowManager` содержит прямые и/или косвенные ссылки на `Context`. Утечки памяти возникают из-за того, что хранятся ссылки (в данном случае косвенные) на `Context` в статическом поле.

Организуйте код так, чтобы `sDefaultWindowManager` не был `static`, и утечка должна исчезнуть.

Comment: Ссылки sDefaultWindowManager у меня нет

Comment: А поворот экрана поддерживаете? Можете прислать код, где вешаете клик лисенер в CurrentSongFragment?

Comment: Поворот не поддерживаем. Добавил обработки нажатия.